# How to element from Json object in java

Tags: java, json

This is my json object when i invoke API

job

```
{
    "path": "/",
    "isBase64Encoded": false,
    "requestContext": {
        "resourceId": "20gm43r4fa",
        "resourcePath": "/",
        "httpMethod": "POST",
        "extendedRequestId": "GO6ktGL_IAMFaLA=",
        "requestTime": "13/Jan/2020:09:53:34 +0000",
        "path": "/",
        "accountId": "***",
        "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
        "stage": "test-invoke-stage",
        "domainPrefix": "testPrefix",
        "requestTimeEpoch": 1578909214062,
        "requestId": "dgdfg-ad12-431a-b1b9-***",
        "identity": {
            "accountId": "***",
            "caller": "345345:a.b@***.com",
            "apiKey": "test-invoke-api-key",
            "sourceIp": "test-invoke-source-ip",
            "accessKey": "&&YY&&YH",
            "userArn": "arn:aws:sts::***:assumed-role/****-PowerUser/ab.dx@****.com",
            "apiKeyId": "test-invoke-api-key-id",
            "userAgent": "aws-internal/3 aws-sdk-java/1.11.690 Linux/4.9.184-0.1.ac.235.83.329.metal1.x86_64 OpenJDK_64-Bit_Server_VM/25.232-b09 java/1.8.0_232 vendor/Oracle_Corporation",
            "user": "345345345:Sa.b@***.com"
        },
        "domainName": "testPrefix.testDomainName",
        "apiId": "dfgdf"
    },
    "resource": "/",
    "httpMethod": "POST",
    "body": "{\"ID\":\"sup-9749-0e710000fd04\",\"VERSION\":1,\"AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_TP\":null}"
}
```

Body of the JSON is something like this

bodyofJson

```
{
    "ID": "sup-9749-0e710000fd04",
    "VERSION": 1,
    "ACTION_TYPE": "NEW_CASE",
    "EVENT_TYPE": "WORLDCHECK"
}
```

I need to get the body of the json and key as ID which is inside Body json .
I am able to get Body but not able to get ID from body json

This is what i am doing

```
JSONObject job = new JSONObject(json);
System.out.println("****job*******"+job);
String bodyofJson = job.getString("body");
System.out.println("****bodyofJson*******"+bodyofJson);
```

The position of the ID can be changing also so thats why i am not getting based on index

Please suggest

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly, but if `body` itself contains JSON, can't you just parse it as you did with `json` and get the `ID` field?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca i tried that but it gives me error

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you tried and the error it gives.

Comment: I see that in the job example you gave, `body` has value `"{\"ID\":\"sup-9749-0e710000fd04\",\"VERSION\":1,\"AUDIT_EVENT_TO_DATE_TP\":null}"` which you won't be able to parse as json because it's not valid (`null` is not a valid value. `"null"`, notice the quotation marks, is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`body` key further contains a json. So, we need to parse it as `JSONObject` and get the value of `ID`.

Here is the code:

```
JSONObject job = new JSONObject(json);
System.out.println("****job*******"+job);
String bodyofJson = job.getString("body");
System.out.println("****bodyofJson*******"+bodyofJson);
// Parse bodyofJson as JSONObject
JSONObject bodyJsonObj = new JSONObject(bodyofJson);
System.out.println(bodyJsonObj.get("ID"));
```